# Configuring TeamCity + NUnit unit tests so files can be loaded properly

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nunit, continuous-integration, teamcity

In a nutshell, I have a solution that builds fine in the IDE, and the unit tests all run fine with the NUnit GUI (via the NUnitit VS2008 plugin).  However, when I execute my TeamCity build runner, all unit tests that require file access (e.g. for running tests against specific XML files), I just get System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundExceptions.

The reason for this is clear: it's looking for those supporting XML files loaded by various unit tests in the wrong folder.

The way my unit tests are structured looks like this:

```
+-- project folder
    +-- unit tests folder
        +-- test.xml
        +-- test.cs
    +-- project file.xaml
    +-- project file.xaml.cs
```

All of my projects own their own UnitTests folder, which contains the .cs file and any XML files, XML Schemas, etc that are necessary to run the tests.

So when I write my test.cs, I have it look for "test.xml" in the code because they are in the same folder (actually, I do something like ....\unit tests\test.xml, but that's kind of silly).  As I said before, the tests run great in NUnit.  But that's because the unit tests are part of the project.  When running the unit tests from TeamCity, I am executing them against the assemblies that get copied to the main app's output folder.  These unit test XML files should *not* be copied willy-nilly to the output folder just to make the tests pass.

Can anyone suggest a better method of organizing my unit tests in each project (which are dependencies for the main app), such that I can execute the unit tests from NUnit **and** from the TeamCity build runner?  The only other option I can come up with is to just put the testing XML data in code, rather than loading it from a file.  I would rather not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, sleeping on a question before posting it is the best thing to do.  I should have known that I should just enter the relative paths of the assemblies' own project debug folder.  Problem solved.